# C, Why there is a Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int KEY;
    if(isdigit(argv[1]))
    {
        KEY = (int)argv[1];
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key");
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%i\n",argc);
}
```

I can't find out the problem when I type the following

[image]

How do I fix it?

Comment: did you pass any argument when it's running ?

Comment: @long.kl Look at linked 1

Comment: You are passing eew which is a string/char pointer not a character, please correct that and check

Comment: `KEY = (int)argv[1];` is taking the address of the string in argv[1] and saves it into `KEY` it does not do a conversion to int as you might think. Use `atoi()` for this.

Comment: The behavior of `isdigit` is undefined if the argument is not EOF or in the range 0 through 0xFF, inclusive. The `argv[1]` is a *pointer* not an integer. Please pay attention to at least 2 compiler warnings.

Comment: @WeatherVane isdigit is a function in <ctype.h>. Also, I have type else here, why the else condition doesn't work?

Comment: The function `isdigit()` takes an `int` argument. You are passing `char*` argument, which when converted to an integer is possibly very large, out of the range of values accepted by `isdigit()`. The result of the consequent *undefined behavior* here was a crash. In other words, `isdigit()` is not required to behave gracefully. The `else` didn't work because the program execution did not get that far, it crashed. I guess you intended: `if(isdigit(argv[1][0]))` but even then, you have failed to check `argc` to test if there is actually a valid program argument `argv[1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a high-level language with various syntax sugar features.

##### Important Notes:

- Conversion of `const char *` to `int` is not done by just *type-casting* it.
- `isdigit()` works only for `int` (single characters), not `const char *` it will cause [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).
- `argc` is the length of pointer array `argv`
- `string` is not a valid type for `main()` function arguments, it should be `int main(int argc, char const **argv) { }`
- Must check whether `argv[1]` even exists or not
- Once you print the usage your program should exit
- Any error message should be printed on `stderr`
- Must Use `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`, which is defined in the header file `stdlib.h`, when exiting the application, or use `return EXIT_FAILURE;` if something goes wrong.

##### Final Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const **argv)
{
    if(argc == 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <KEY>", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; argv[1][i]; i++)
    {
        if(!isdigit(argv[1][i]))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "expected only integer value\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    // we don't need to check whether `argv[1]` is all digit or not at this point 
    int KEY = strtod(argv[1], NULL);
    printf("argc = %d\n", argc);
    printf("KEY = %d\n", KEY);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Two things: CS50 defines `string` as `char*` (like it or not). Also `int main()` is *not* required to return a value. It is the only function which has an implicit `return 0;` when missing.

Comment: @WeatherVane I know that but still good practice is good practice. And I'm not a CS50 student.